# Finding Items That Haven't Had A Usage Date in the last 60 days

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query to find items that haven't had any activity in the last 60 days (so ledger date is greater than 60 days). From what I can tell the below query is only showing me the first action outside of that range, but I have items that are showing up inside the 60 day range.
I hope I explained this well enough.

```
   SELECT il.BranchID
  ,il.ItemID
  ,i.Description1
  ,MAX(il.LedgerDate) AS "MostRecentDate"
  ,il.TransactionType
  ,iv.Quantity
  FROM [Latitude].[dbo].[ItemLedger] il
 join Inventory iv on il.ItemID = iv.ItemID
 join Item i on il.ItemID = i.ItemID
 where il.TransactionType in ('ord.pick')
 and il.LedgerDate <DateAdd(day,DateDiff(day,0,GetDate()),-60)
 and il.BranchID in ('Waverly','Mattoon')
  and iv.Quantity>'0'
  and i.ItemID <> '<Generic>'
 group by  il.ItemID,il.BranchID,i.Description1, il.TransactionType, iv.Quantity
 order by iv.Quantity desc
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DateAdd and DateDiff are product specific functions.)

Comment: Use `HAVING` clause for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean by DBMS? SQL Server Management Studio if that's what you are asking
For the having clause can you give me an example?

Comment: DBMS = Database Management System also referred to as RDBMS (Relational Database Management System). In your case, it's SQL Server but it matters which version of SQL Server (2012, 2016, 2022, etc...). If you don't know, run @@Version in Management Studio. It will tell you what version you're on.

Answer (score 0):

Without having data to test against, I'm not sure how well this works but I think it solves your issue.

I used a CTE to get the max ledger date for each Item and then cleaned up the rest to make things more readable.

```
; WITH CTE AS 
  (SELECT ItemID
        , MAX(LedgerDate) AS MostRecentDate
     FROM ItemLedger
 GROUP BY ItemID
  )
  SELECT led.BranchID
       , led.ItemID
       , itm.Description1
       , cte.MostRecentDate
       , led.TransactionType
       , inv.Quantity
    FROM ItemLedger led
    JOIN Inventory  inv ON led.ItemID = inv.ItemID
    JOIN Item       itm ON led.ItemID = itm.ItemID
    JOIN CTE        cte ON led.ItemID = cte.ItemID
   WHERE cte.MostRecentDate < DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())
     AND led.TransactionType = 'ord.pick'
     AND led.BranchID IN ('Waverly','Mattoon')
     AND inv.Quantity > '0'
     AND itm.ItemID <> '<Generic>'
ORDER BY inv.Quantity desc
```

A couple questions,

1. TransactionType IN ('ord.pick'). Did you mean IN ('ord', 'pick'), or = 'ord.pick'?
2. Quantity > '0'. Why is zero in quotes? Are you storing numbers as strings? Should it be Quantity > 0?

Comment: That was very helpful but I have one issue and not 100% sure how to fix it. The item IDs are showing up multiple times. I am assuming its one for each line on the ledger table.
As for your questions 1) it is ord.pick because you could have ord.ship or something similiar.
2 not sure really my have been a typo

Comment: Again this is difficult without data. My best guess is duplicates are coming from the WHERE. Things that stand out include itm.ItemID <> generic could return multiple other possibilities, also there are two BranchIDs. Combinations of those two could create dozens of duplicates.

Comment: So I went down to one branch and the generic is because actually have item ID called <generic>  and we don't want that one it  in

Here is an example:
BranchID ItemID Description1 MostRecentDate TransactionType Quantity
WAVERLY 66570703 2 PACK FOREARM LIFTING STRAPS 2022-12-16 11:30:05.000 ORD.PICK 2832.0000
WAVERLY 66570703 2 PACK FOREARM LIFTING STRAPS 2022-12-16 11:30:05.000 ORD.PICK 2832.0000
WAVERLY 66570703 2 PACK FOREARM LIFTING STRAPS 2022-12-16 11:30:05.000 ORD.PICK 2832.0000
WAVERLY 66570703 2 PACK FOREARM LIFTING STRAPS 2022-12-16 11:30:05.000 ORD.PICK 2832.0000

Comment: Change the outer SELECT to SELECT DISTINCT.